# The image created by CGContext.makeImage is different from the original text

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cgcontext, quartz-2d

I want to create a mask using text and need to convert the text into an image. But after converting, I found that it did not match exactly with the original text. I conducted the following tests.

```swift
class MyView: NSView{
    
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        guard let g = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext else{ return }
        
        let antialiasing = false //true or false is useless
        g.setAllowsAntialiasing(antialiasing)
        g.setShouldAntialias(antialiasing)
        
        let text: NSString = "HELLO"
        let pos: CGPoint = .init(x: 20, y: 20)
        let font: NSFont = .init(name: "Arial Black", size: 96)!
        var textAttr: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font : font
        ]
        
        //Draw the blue text in new CGContext, generate an image, draw the image in current CGContext
        let image = createImage(dirtyRect: dirtyRect) { g in
            g.setAllowsAntialiasing(antialiasing)
            g.setShouldAntialias(antialiasing)
            
            textAttr[.foregroundColor] = NSColor.blue
            text.draw(at: pos, withAttributes: textAttr)
        }
        g.draw(image!, in: dirtyRect, byTiling: false)
        
        //Draw the yellow text with all same properties
        let attr: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font : font,
            .foregroundColor : NSColor.yellow
        ]
        text.draw(at: pos, withAttributes: attr)
    }

    private func createImage(dirtyRect: NSRect, drawingHandler: ((_ g: CGContext) -> Void)?) -> CGImage?{
        NSGraphicsContext.saveGraphicsState()
        let g = CGContext(data: nil,
                          width: Int(dirtyRect.width),
                          height: Int(dirtyRect.height),
                          bitsPerComponent: 8,
                          bytesPerRow: 0,
                          space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                          bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)!
        NSGraphicsContext.current = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: g, flipped: false)
        drawingHandler?(g)
        let image = g.makeImage()
        NSGraphicsContext.restoreGraphicsState()
        return image
    }
}
```

As can be seen, the two texts cannot completely overlap after being stacked, and the blue text below reveals a circle of edges.

I tried other `createImage` methods, such as creating an `NSImage` and drawing text on it, or creating a `CGLayer` and drawing text on this layer then create the image, and the results were similar.

The only perfect solution is to use the current `CGContext` and disable Anti-aliasing to generate text image. But the problem with this method is that the generated image will contain all the drawn content, some of which may not be necessary for me.

```swift
private func createImage(dirtyRect: NSRect, drawingHandler:((_ g: CGContext) -> Void)?) -> CGImage?{
    drawingHandler?(NSGraphicsContext.current!.cgContext)
    return NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext.makeImage()
}
```

Any solutions?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The `CGContext` that you created and the `CGContext` in `draw(_:)` are not the same type of `CGContext`. The one you created is a bitmap context and the view doesn't use a bitmap context. What are you ultimately trying to do here? Why do you need the two images to be exactly the same? How about drawing both texts using a bitmap context?

Comment: Note, off topic: `dirtyRect` is the part of the view that needs redrawing. If you want to draw in the entire view then use `bounds`.

Comment: @Sweeper I have tried using two NSImage to generate these two texts, but found that they are still different. But your answer made me understand where my problem lies. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing out the `g`s in both `draw(_:)` and `createImage`. They are of different types, so it is not surprising that they behave differently (though I cannot tell you exactly what the difference is).

The two texts do overlap, if you draw into an `NSImage`, using [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/1519860-init), then convert that image to `CGImage` using the current context.

```
private func createImage(dirtyRect: NSRect, drawingHandler: @escaping (_ g: CGContext) -> Void) -> CGImage?{
    let image = NSImage(size: dirtyRect.size, flipped: false) { _ in
        guard let g = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext els { return false }
        drawingHandler(g)
        return true
    }
    // presumably passing context: nil uses the current context,
    // but you can also use context: NSGraphicsContext.current
    return image.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)
}
```

Comment: I also tried to use NSImage for drawing before, and my mistake occurred when converting to cgImage. Thank you.